# Django template: How can I regroup a list of dictionaries by a nested property of each dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm writing a template for a job listings site in which I want to order a set of short-term jobs by date, they are currently grouped by area. The job days are non consecutive and are stored as properties of each job. It's the days that I want the jobs to be ordered by.

I have a list of dictionaries (areas), each of these dictionaries contains key/value pairs for things like fee, location. One of these properties is a list of dates which the job will be on.

```
all_jobs
    area_1
        job_1
           fee
           location
           days
               monday
               thursday
               friday
        job_2
           fee
           location
           days
               wednesday
     area_2
        job_3
           fee
           location
           days
               tuesday
```

Hopefully that diagram clarifies the structure of the data. I have looked at regroup, but I don't think this will work since the dates are properties are nested in another list, rather than being a direct property of the job.

It would be highly preferential for me to do this in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a custom filter would be one direction to take since it is not straightforward to use regroup, you can write a custom filter; pass your lists of dictionaries to it and using group by using the key that you want to order by or filter with.

Custom filters - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Itertools group by - https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html